# Transferring extension ownership to another user

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an extension that I am thinking about selling, is there a way to transfer ownership to another user? I saw the details about group publishing but it looks like that applies to all published extensions for a user.

Comment: I don't think group publishing requires you to transfer all of your items though.

Answer (score 2):

Crap, Just found this...

https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer

looks like what I was looking for!